# Entities relation, form builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

i have two entities Topic 
and TopicContent
[image]

when i send data from Topic entity, all ok. But when i included TopicContentType to my form builder, a have an error.. Friends, help me please..
[image]

[image]

My controller

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Topic();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('application_club_show', array('id' => $entity->getTopicId())));
    }

    return $this->render('ApplicationClubBundle:Topic:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
 $builder
        ->add('user_id', 'hidden')
        ->add('topic_title')
        ->add('topic_tags')
        ->add('topic_publish', 'hidden')
        ->add('topic_user_ip', 'hidden')
        ->add('topic_count_read', 'hidden')
        ->add('topic_count_comment', 'hidden')
    ;

    $builder->add('topic_content', new \Application\ClubBundle\Form\TopicContentType());
```

TypicType

```
$builder
        ->add('user_id', 'hidden')
        ->add('topic_title')
        ->add('topic_tags')
        ->add('topic_publish', 'hidden')
        ->add('topic_user_ip', 'hidden')
        ->add('topic_count_read', 'hidden')
        ->add('topic_count_comment', 'hidden')
    ;

    $builder->add('topic_content', new \Application\ClubBundle\Form\TopicContentType());
```

TopicContentType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('topic_id')
        ->add('topic_text')
    ;
}
```

TopicContent Entity

```
<?php

namespace Application\ClubBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class TopicContent
{
    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $topic_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $topic_text;

    /**
     * @var \Application\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic
     */
    private $topic;


    /**
     * Set topic_id
     *
     * @param integer $topicId
     * @return TopicContent
     */
    public function setTopicId($topicId)
    {
        $this->topic_id = $topicId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic_id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getTopicId()
    {
        return $this->topic_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set topic_text
     *
     * @param string $topicText
     * @return TopicContent
     */
    public function setTopicText($topicText)
    {
        $this->topic_text = $topicText;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic_text
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTopicText()
    {
        return $this->topic_text;
    }

    /**
     * Set topic
     *
     * @param \Application\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic $topic
     * @return TopicContent
     */
    public function setTopic(\Application\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic $topic = null)
    {
        $this->topic = $topic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get topic
     *
     * @return \Application\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic 
     */
    public function getTopic()
    {
        return $this->topic;
    }
}
```

Topic Entity

```
    /**
 * Add topic_content
 *
 * @param \Application\ClubBundle\Entity\TopicContent $topicContent
 * @return Topic
 */
public function setTopicContent(\Application\ClubBundle\Entity\TopicContent $topicContent)
{
    $this->topic_content[] = $topicContent;

    return $this;
}
```

my entities relatoins
Topic

```
Application\ClubBundle\Entity\Topic:
type: entity
table: topic
id:
    topic_id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    topic_title:
        type: string
        length: 200
oneToMany:
    topic_content:
        targetEntity: TopicContent
        mappedBy: topic
    topic_tag:
        targetEntity: TopicTag
        mappedBy: topic
        cascade: ["persist"]
```

TopicContent

```
Application\ClubBundle\Entity\TopicContent:
type: entity
table: topic_content
id:
    topic_id:
        type: integer
fields:
    topic_text:
        type: text
oneToOne:
    topic:
        targetEntity: Topic
        inversedBy: topic_content
        joinColumn:
            name: topic_id
            referencedColumnName: topic_id
        cascade: ["persist"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer in the error message displayed by Symfony: you need to persist the `Topic` entity AND the `TopicContent` entity. To do that you must define a `cascade={"persist"}` on the relation.

**Edit:**

Another way to persist the `TopicContent` would be to do it explicitly in the form processing function:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $content = $entity->getTopicContent();
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->persist($content);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('application_club_show', array('id' => $entity->getTopicId())));
}
```

Comment: how to add persist in yaml forma?? thanks  http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/03/16/46d/d13/a4184eab6738575ba80bdd1907850ca62e1f1073.jpg

Comment: You can find all the information here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html

Comment: Can you post the entire code where you define your relation?

Comment: In the `Topic` mapping, you define a `OneToMany` relation, but in the `TopicContent` you define a `OneToOne`. Also you haven't define a cascade persist on the `TopicContent` relation but only on the Tag realtion.

Comment: i've added the cascade persist into my topicContent.. not work (((-:

Comment: Did you also correct the type of the relation? `OneToMany` -> `OneToOne`. Also clear the cache between each try, and use the Symfony debugger tool to check if there is any invalid entity.

Comment: thanks for help.. but now i have an error "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'topic_id' cannot be null" because, the topic entity id is auto increment, but the contentTopic entity id is not auto increment, he is in relation with topic entity id.. i don't know what to doing....

Comment: I've added another solution in my answer, maybe this one will work for you.

Comment: thaks friend!!! works!!!!!!!! i  spent all time today , to create this functional.. thanks!